# Is there a difference between topological defects and topological soliton?

Tags: field-theory, topological-field-theory, solitons, topological-defects

Is there a difference between topological defects and topological soliton? Or are these objects the same thing? I ask this because it very common find some papers whose the authors itself refer, for example, the domain wall's, monopoles, cosmic string, etc, as topological defects, while in others, the same objects are called of topological solitons. As the authors aren't specific about this  It seems that defects and topological solitons are the same things. But will be this idea conceptually correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. In static situations, both are strictly the same thing. But, when analyze the dynamic of these structures, we see that they are differents.

Comment: Could you expand this a bit more please?